# Передать массив параметром в открытие окна

Tags: javascript

Можно ли передать массив в виде параметра на страницу, используя window.open?

Comment: добавьте в урл  параметром содержимое вашего массива. Если массив  разумных размеров и не имеет какой-то сложносочиненной структуры, то сработает

Comment: Собственно в этом и вопрос, какой вида должна быть запись в урле. я знаю что точное значение передать можно используя знак "=", а вот с массивом как?

Comment: `window.open('index.php?x[1]=1&x[2]=2');` или `window.open('index.php?x[]=1&x[]=2');`

Comment: Но если страница на вашем же домене, то посмотрите в сторону localStorage.

Comment: ... но, разумеется, загружаемая страница должна уметь обрабатывать параметры из URL.

Comment: @SergeSeredenko Можно через `window.top` получить доступ к глобальным функциям родительского окна. Но все это очень дурная архитектура.

Comment: @VisioN это то естественно)

Comment: @VisioN Я так понимаю, это не сработает, если первое окно закрыть.

Comment: @SergeSeredenko Да там масса вариантов, при котором это не сработает. Желательно, конечно, знать что за массив там отгружается.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно использовать JSON. С помощью [JSON.stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) генерируете JSON, с помощью [JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) восстанавливаете объект или массив. Через window.location.href и decodeURI можно получить запрос с JSON. Но нужно помнить, что у некоторых браузеров может быть ограничение на длину url.

Answer (score 0):

Мне предложили использовать session storage.
Думаю это будет куда лучше. А уже на открывающейся странице буду парсить storage.
Спасибо всем за помощь

Comment: Не пишите "Спасибо" в качестве ответа. Когда ваша [репутация](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/reputation) достигнет необходимого уровня, Вы сможете [проголосовать за вопросы и ответы](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up), которые вы сочтете полезными.